# How to implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>'?

Tags: c#, oop

When I assign a `Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>` to a `IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>`, I get the following error:

> Compilation error (line 27, col 9): Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The error is quite clear. A cast is missing. Why do I need a cast here? `Dictionary<T,U>` implements `IDictionary<T,U>` and `HashSet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{   
    public class A
    {
        public IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> D { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> H { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<int>{1,2,1};
        var a = new A { H = hashSet };
        PrintCollection(a.H);

        var d = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>{{ 3, hashSet  }};
        a.D = d; // error here
        PrintCollection(a.D.First().Value);
    }

    public static void PrintCollection(IEnumerable<int> collections)
    {
        foreach (var item in collections)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gVFzIn)

Comment: I'd suggest reading about variance in C#.

Comment: It's because for `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `TValue` is not covariant.

Comment: As the duplicate *and* Tom's answer explain, what you ask is unsafe and therefore prohibited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. If you take a variable of type `IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>` and try to add say an `IList<int>` as a value - which by the type of the variable, you should be able to do - then in your case that actually entails adding an invalid member to your `Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>`. You can't cast this type because that would be using the type system to say something that isn't true - that any `IEnumerable<int>` can be added to the dictionary - it cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Variance in C# is opt-in only when safe to do so.

`IEnumrable<out T>` supports covariance but `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not.

Notice the `out` keyword; that allows covariant assignment when the type is generally read-only.

Now imagine if `IDictionary` was covariant:

```
IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();
dict.Add(1, new List<int>()); // oh dear, added a list to a Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>
```